# store same value to multiple variable

Tags: python

i was wondering if there was a faster way to set those below

```
Max_age  = 21
Suzy_age = 21
Mia_age  = 21
```

why not writing

```
Max_age and Suzy_age and Mia_age = 21
```

or even

```
Max_age = Suzy_age = Mia_age = 21
```

I'm new to python and this kind of code seems really intuitive, but somehow there's no one liner like thoses ? am i wrong ? please tell me i'm wrong.

Comment: i get that we can put all object in a list, but i asked for a one liner.

Comment: Do you have to pay for lines of code?

Comment: Your last example is ok

Comment: `Max_age = Suzy_age = Mia_age = 21` is already valid.

Comment: You should try checking if the examples you are thinking of work already, in your case the second one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is invalid

```py
a and b and c = 1
```

will cause an error, since `a and b` is a binary expression, which is a value, not a variable, so you can't assign to it.

the second one is valid

```py
a = b = c = 1
```

will run as in the order

```
a = (b = (c = 1))
```

since the assignment is right-associative. The assignment `c = 1` evaluates to `1`, so that will be assigned to `b`, and so on.

However, in python it's common to write multiple assignments like

```py
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

which is called *tuple unpacking*

Whether that's preferable to having one assignment per line, is a matter of style and context.

Comment: *"assignment is right-associative. The assignment c = 1 returns 1, so that will be assigned to b, and so on."* Umm, no, that's not how assignments work in python. They don't "return" anything, and they're executed left-to-right. (`a` is assigned first, then `b`, then `c`.)

Comment: I think it should be important to clarify, that `a = (b = (c = 1))` is not a valid python statement as you can't assign a value to a global variable definition. `a = b = c = 1` is a separate python syntax rule.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: `a` is assigned to the result of the expression `b = ...`. So, the right expression has to be evaluated first. How could `a` be assigned first?

Comment: `b = ...` is not an expression at all. Assignments are *statements*, and they're executed left-to-right.

Comment: I'm not sure anything is "assigned first" ... as noted by @kuco23, multiple assignment is a separate syntactical construct in python that results in a parse tree saying "Set a,b,c all to 1"

Comment: @Aran-Fey: **it is** an expression. see the grammar specification.

Comment: @blue_note It is a [**statement**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) ... and they are physically executed left to right ... *and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.*. (`dis.dis("a=b=c=1")` will demonstrate the left to right nature)

Comment: @donkopotamus: so is every every expression: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements

Comment: @blue_note That every Expression is an Expression_Statement, does not make an Assignment_Statement an Expression.  It remains that `a=b=c` is an assignment, it is evaluated left-to-right and it is not "right-associative", which would require each part to be value producing (i.e an expression).  (Although this is just a disagreement about a trivial part of a perfectly fine answer!)

Comment: @donkopotamus: if `b=c` does not produce a value, what is `a` assigned to??

Comment: @blue_note As noted in the language reference, each *target_list* is assigned, **left-to-right** to the *resulting object*.  The *resulting object* is `1` and each of `a`, `b` and `c` is a target list, meaning that `a=b=c=1` sets `a` directly to `1`, then `b` directly to `1` and `c` directly to 1, **in that order**.  Parsing the expression using `ast`, or disassembling it using `dis` will both demonstrate that `b` is not set to the value of the subexpression `c=1` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
Max_age, Suzy_age, Mia_age = 21, 21, 21
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
Max_age, Suzy_age, Mia_age = [21] * 3
```